# Infinity Ajax Request When Drop Change in Knockout MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using Knockout MVC in my project.  I try to pass the viewModel to when Drop Down changing . but when I try this method call several times and the alert "ok" invoke continuesley. Can any one please help me on this??

```
$(function () {
  $('#rmch').change(function () {             
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("DropChange", "Home")',
      type: 'POST',
      data: ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.redirect) {
          location.href = resolveUrl(data.url);
        }
        else {
          //ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("p_scentsFH"));
          alert("Ok");
          ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
       alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
      },
    });   
  });    
});
```

### My Json Method

```
public JsonResult DropChange(HotelModel hotelmod)
{
  //hmodel.RoomModel = new List<RoomModel>();
  //for (int i = 1; i <= hmodel.NoOfRooms; i++)
  //{
  //    hmodel.RoomModel.Add(new RoomModel { adultsDrp = ListItems.GetList(1, 6), childDrop = ListItems.GetList(0, 5) });
  //    //hmodel.RoomModel.Add(new RoomModel { });
  //}
  var jjj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hotelmod);
  return Json(hotelmod);
}
```

### My View

```
<div class="search-tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="hotels-tab">
    <form id="searchfrm">
      <div class="title-container">
        <h2 class="search-title">Search and Book Hotels</h2>
        <p>We're bringing you a new level of comfort.</p>
        <i class="soap-icon-hotel"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="search-content">
        <h5 class="title">Where</h5>
        <label>Your Destination</label>
        @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.Destination, new { @class = "input-text full-width", @placeholder = "Any destination, country, city code" })
        @ko.Html.Hidden(new { @Id = "DesCode" }).Value(m => m.DesCode)
        <hr>
        <h5 class="title">When</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>Check In</label>
            <div class="datepicker-wrap">
            @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.CheckInDate, new { @class = "input-text full-width" })
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label>Check Out</label>
          <div class="datepicker-wrap">
            @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.CheckOutDate, new { @class = "input-text full-width" })
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label>ROOMS</label>
          <div class="selector">
            @ko.Html.DropDownList(m => m.RoomList, new { @class = "full-width jkl", @id = "rmch" }, "Text", "Value").Value(m => m.NoOfRooms)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="p_scentsFH">
        @using (var rmModel = ko.Foreach(m => m.RoomModel))
        {      
          <h5 class="title">Room 1</h5><div class="row">                                                    
          <div class="col-xs-3">                                                        
            <label>ADULTS</label>
            <div class="selectorgen">
              @rmModel.Html.DropDownList(m => m.adultsDrp, new { @class = "full-width" },"Text","Value").Value(m=>m.adultscount)                                                            
            </div>                                                        
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">                                               
            <label>KIDS</label>
            <div class="selectorgen">
              @rmModel.Html.DropDownList(m => m.childDrop, new { @class = "full-width" }, "Text", "Value").Value(m => m.childcount)                                                                                                                                                            
            </div>                                                        
          </div>                                                
          <div class="agecls">
            @using(var chage=rmModel.Foreach(m=>m.childage))
            { 
              <div class="col-xs-3">                                                        
                <label>Child</label>
                <div class="selectorgen">   
                  @chage.Html.DropDownList(m => m.ageDrop, new { @class = "full-width" },"Text","Value").Value(m=>m.Age)                                                                                              
                </div>
              </div>
            }
            </div>
          </div><hr>
        }
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="full-width uppercase">Search Cheap Hotels</button>
    </div>
    }                   
    </form>
  </div>                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that when the redirection did not happen then on else part your view model binding is causing your dropdown value to get changed and hence the dropdown on change event triggers again and again. Make sure you are not changing the selected item of your dropdown from ajax call.